# Intel gm45 express chipset will now only display on computer and goes black when I plug the VGA

Tags: graphics-card

Intel gm45 express chipset will now only display on computer and goes black when I plug the VGA extension to my sony bravia which now remains black and says unsupported signal.

I can no longer extend the display or adjust the resolution on the second monitor or TV that is and its only at 800x600

Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator Driver for Mobile Report:

```
Report Date:        03/03/2015
Report Time[hr:mm:ss]:  19:58:34
Driver Version:     7.15.10.1511
Operating System:       Windows Vista (TM) Home Premium* , Service Pack 2 (6.0.6002)
Default Language:       English
DirectX* Version:       10.0
Physical Memory:        2910 MB
Minimum Graphics Memory:    128 MB
Maximum Graphics Memory:    1327 MB
Graphics Memory in Use: 25 MB
Processor:      x86 family 6 Model 15 Stepping 13
Processor Speed:        1993 MHZ
Vendor ID:      8086
Device ID:      2A42
Device Revision:        07
```

Accelerator Information:

```
Accelerator in Use:     Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family
Video BIOS:     1654.0
Current Graphics Mode:  1280 by 800 True Color (59 Hz)
```

Devices Connected to the Graphics Accelerator:

```
Active Notebook Displays: 1
```

Notebook:

```
Monitor Name:       Generic PnP Monitor
Display Type:       Digital
Gamma Value:        3.54
DDC2 Protocol:      Supported
Maximum Image Size: Horizontal: Not Available
            Vertical:   Not Available
Monitor Supported Modes:
1280 by 800 (60 Hz)
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds very much like your graphics drivers are corrupt.

Try reinstalling your graphics drivers ([you can download them here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=Mobile%20Intel%C2%AE%20GM45%20Express%20Chipset%20%28embedded%29))

If you have installed any other hardware/software recently - it may also be worth trying an uninstall of that first.

Another possibility is a system restore if you have it enabled on your PC.  I notice from your post above you are running Vista, so [these instructions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-vista/turn-back-time-on-your-pc-undo-system-changes-with-system-restore) should help (Start > System restore in search box > system restore > select a restore point > go)

Another possibility is a damaged cable - do you have another one you can try?

Comment: Wheew! Have it going! Did a graphics driver uninstall.OOPs .Came back in safe mode. Installed an intel graphics driver that still only had one display. Went to sony for the latest grapphics driver computer and sysytem specific and installed it. Still only one display. Downloaded a utility to see if the down load was working and it uninstalled something and whoohoo!.More options but happy in clone at the moment. Thanks for your help.an now watch the surfing !!

Comment: Awesome.  Please feel free to accept this answer or upvote it if it helped with your problem.  Anything else we can help with, let me know.